# How do I see if a symbol package has been published for a given Nuget package?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, pdb-files, symbol-server

I want to use a debugger to step through the code of an [open-source](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect), public [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/2.0.1) that my project references. My understanding is that if the package publishes a symbol package I should be able to do this.

It's not working, and I can see that it's because the .pdb file can not be located:

[image]

Presumably this is because either:

a) I haven't correctly set up Visual Studio to load symbols from the right place (the info online about this is all very confusing and contradictory), or...

b) The package in question doesn't publish a symbols package.

How do I check if b is the issue? **Is there an easy way to check if a symbol package has been published for a given NuGet package?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I check if b is the issue? Is there an easy way to check if a symbol package has been published for a given NuGet package?

You can use the nuget.exe CLI Reference `list` to list the version of that package on the symbol sources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-list

The list command:

```
nuget.exe list Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect -AllVersion -Prerelease -source https://nuget.smbsrc.net
```

After test, I found the symbol package of that package has not been published:

[image]

Note: The  package `LSGTestNuGetPackage` is a test symbol package, which I published before.

Comment: This solution no longer works. Your command prints the following output: `Unable to load the service index for source https://nuget.smbsrc.net.
  An error occurred while sending the request.
  The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.
  The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.`